# Access Buttons VBA Problems and Subform Issues

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, vba

Im working on a key inventory database. Something to manage who signs out room keys and when they bring them back in. I've created the tables I plan on using and have started working on the forms. However, I am having trouble getting the forms/subforms to work as desired.

I've created buttons to add/edit/delete/etc the records in the subform which are a result of the tables. I've coded the buttons based on an old project I did in my DB class (someone else did the forms then, I did queries). I can't seem to get them working. So far, I've only coded the buttons for "mainKeys" form so far.

I've noticed the main form shows 1 of 14 records whereas the forms from my old project only showed all records in the subforms.

Here's the Access file: http://jumpshare.com/b/W7AKih

Here's my old project (this is what im trying to copy): http://jumpshare.com/b/r7Y6O1

Here's the code for the buttons:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
If Me.keyID.Tag & "" = "" Then
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO KEYS(KEY_ID, ROOM, DRAWER)" & _
        " VALUES(" & Me.keyID & ",'" & Me.roomID & "'," & Me.drawerID & ")"
          subKey.Form.Requery
Else
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE KEYS " & _
    " SET KEY_ID=" & Me.keyID & _
    ", ROOM='" & Me.roomID & "'" & _
    ", DRAWER='" & Me.drawerID & "'" & _
    " WHERE KEY_ID=" & Me.keyID.Tag
End If
cmdReset_Click
subKey.Form.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cmdBack_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
If Not (Me.subKey.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.subKey.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
    If MsgBox("Confirm Deletion?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM KEYS" & _
            " WHERE KEY_ID=" & Me.subKey.Form.Recordset.Fields("KEY_ID")
                Me.subKey.Form.Requery
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdEdit_Click()
If Not (Me.subKey.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.subKey.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
        With Me.subKey.Form.Recordset
            Me.keyID = .Fields("KEY_ID")
            Me.roomID = .Fields("ROOM")
            Me.drawerID = .Fields("DRAWER")
            Me.keyID.Tag = .Fields("KEY_ID")
            Me.cmdAdd.Caption = "Update Record"
            Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = False
        End With
End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdExit_Click()
 DoCmd.Close
End Sub

Private Sub cmdReset_Click()
    Me.keyID = ""
    Me.roomID = ""
    Me.drawerID = ""

    Me.keyID.SetFocus
    Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = True
    Me.cmdAdd.Caption = "ADD KEY"
    Me.keyID.Tag = ""
End Sub
```

From what I can see the Reset & Exit buttons work just fine, the add/delete/update records do not. 
Also, this is a small project I am working on for an office in my school. If anyone has any recommendations from what they see in the file that would be great.

Comment: shouldn't you update the database after changing it? sth about: `Me.update()`

Comment: maybe but I think that's what the "Me.subKey.Form.Requery" does. I looked at the file im using as a guide and there is no me.update() and it seems to work fine.

Comment: but there is no requery or whatever in the Edit function, try to check if that works after adding it

Comment: I added this but im getting data type errors. Ive reuploaded the file with the changes you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The reason nothing is happening is that the event line in your database is set to `[Embedded Macro]` rather than `[Event Procedure]`, so the code you have posted is never run. It is always wise to set a breakpoint when you have a problem to see if the code is reached.

After that, to my mind, you are going to far too much trouble in one way and far too little in another. Instead of writing all that insert code when Access will handle an addition to the subform very nicely, write a lot more checking code to make sure the data is in good shape.

Comment: This is my first go at VBA. So I don't know how to write checking good. The fields however are associated with tables so I assume it will use the types from the tables and the corresponding input masks to prevent users from entering incorrect information. Currently they are unbounded but I plan on changing that.

Comment: I've changed all the buttons to [Event Procedure]. The 
"Add Key" button now works. However, when I try to edit a record, I get a data type mismatch in criteria expression. 
The data type when I edit hasn't changed so I don't understand why im getting this error. I also get the same error when trying to delete a record

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Which form? BTW You really would be much better working to MS Access' strengths.

Comment: I'll reupload the access file. Gimme a sec please. And what do you mean by Access' strenghts? [Here](http://jumpshare.com/b/W7AKih)

Comment: Create a form and subform using the wizards. Look at how nice it is.

Comment: Yea I did...that doesnt tell me anything or solve any of my button problems. My main issue isnt creating forms, its adding functionality to them.

Comment: You are adding unnecessary functionality. To edit a line, just edit it. To add a line just add it. You do not need buttons. Use code to check the data, not to add and edit.

Comment: Im adding these buttons because the user im making this for wants all the functionality in simple forms. She doesn't want to use the table at all.

Comment: Do not use the table. Use continuous forms, single forms, subforms, lots of forms, just keep it simple.

Comment: So ur basically saying, unlock my forms & subforms to allow the user to just write  information in there.

Comment: Yes. Check that the data is correct, let Access handle everything else.

Comment: Yea I guess I could do it like that but then I might as well have them just enter information into a table. Theres no difference really.

Comment: There is a **huge** difference. You control the input with checks of the data. You organize the data into sensible forms and subforms. You create reports.

Comment: Can you give me an example of these checks. I dont understand what you mean when you refer to this. Im really sorry but dealing with forms is really new to me.