# Add/Edit Button Giving Datatype Error

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a main and subform. I have text boxes in the main form that will allow me to add/edit information into the subform. Add works fine but when I try to edit a record, the information of the selected record shows up in the textbox like I want to but when I try to update, I get datatype error. Also when I try to delete a record I also get a datatype error.

Im trying to copy the work one of my partners for a previous project did (CarDealership). Im hoping to get similar functionality into the KeyInventory DB.
Here are the files im using: http://jumpshare.com/b/t7Lot8

***I've only done the code for buttons found on the  mainKeys form***

**Error Reproduction:** I click remove key, get the conformation dialog. Select yes which produces "Run-Time error "3464": Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression"

This is the code for the add/update button:

```
 Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    If Me.keyID.Tag & "" = "" Then
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO KEYS(KEY_ID, ROOM, DRAWER)" & _
            " VALUES(" & Me.keyID & ",'" & Me.roomID & "'," & Me.drawerID & ")"
              subKey.Form.Requery
    Else
        CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE KEYS " & _
        " SET KEY_ID=" & Me.keyID & _
        ", ROOM='" & Me.roomID & "'" & _
        ", DRAWER='" & Me.drawerID & "'" & _
        " WHERE KEY_ID=" & Me.keyID.Tag
    End If

    cmdReset_Click

    subKey.Form.Requery
    End Sub
```

This is the code for the Delete button:

```
  Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    If Not (Me.subKey.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.subKey.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
        If MsgBox("Confirm Deletion?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM KEYS" & _
                " WHERE KEY_ID=" & Me.subKey.Form.Recordset.Fields("KEY_ID")
                    Me.subKey.Form.Requery
        End If
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253306/access-buttons-vba-problems-and-subform-issues/14257729#comment19803465_14257729

Comment: This is a more specific question. The other question was about none of the buttons working. This is a question about the specific error im getting. I hope that's okay.

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: K lets say I select the row for a certain key: I click remove key, get the conformation dialog. Select yes which produces "Run-Time error "3464": Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the line which triggers your "*Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression*" error ...

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM KEYS" & _
    " WHERE KEY_ID=" & Me.subKey.Form.Recordset.Fields("KEY_ID")
```

...  give yourself an opportunity to examine the statement you're asking the db engine to execute.  Replace that line in `cmdDelete_Click()` with this code:

```vb
Dim strSql As String
strSql = "DELETE FROM KEYS" & _
    " WHERE KEY_ID=" & Me.subKey.Form.Recordset.Fields("KEY_ID")
Debug.Print strSql ' <- prints to Immediate window
CurrentDb.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError
```

Then, with your form in Form View, click the command button which leads to the error.  And when you get the error, go to the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>) and view the `DELETE` statement.  If the problem with that statement isn't obvious, you can copy the statement text and paste it into SQL View of a new query for testing.  Show it to us if you need more help.

Note: This suggestion will not fix the error.  It is intended only to help you diagnose the failing `DELETE` statement.

If the data type of your KEY_ID field is text, add quotes around the number in your DELETE statement similar to this one:

```vb
DELETE FROM KEYS WHERE KEY_ID='7'
```

If that works, revise the code to also include quotes.

```vb
strSql = "DELETE FROM KEYS WHERE KEY_ID='" & _
    Me.subKey.Form.Recordset.Fields("KEY_ID") & "'"
```

Comment: Im not sure if I understand correctly. So What I did was replace the two lines with what your code. I still get the same error. When I debug it highlights " CurrentDb.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError"

Comment: Im sorry but Im not sure how to proceed. First I dont know if i am or replacing my lines with yours or if i am just putting them in a query to get more information. When I put them in a query I get an error saying Invalid SQL statement. When I add it to my lines and hit (ctrl + g) it just brings me to the code view but doesn't provide any more information.

Comment: My suggestion was about changing the code in your `cmdDelete_Click()` subroutine.  After making that change, switch your form to Form View and click the command button.  When the error happens, view the output from `Debug.Print strSql`.  That output will be visible in the Immediate window.

Comment: Wow, I never noticed the Immediate window below. Gimme a sec running it now.

Comment: All it says is "DELETE FROM KEYS WHERE KEY_ID=7" It kinda just tells me what I was trying to do. Im not sure if that's helpful in anyway.

Comment: And what happens when you paste that into SQL View of a new query?  Does it work?  Or do you get the data type mismatch error?

Comment: Ohh thats what I was suppose to Query. Gotcha. Yea I get the same error "Data type mismatch on criteria expression"

Comment: Looking at key id in design view i realized that it is a text type. So I need to put single brackets around my attributes in codeview to represent text, is this correct?

Comment: When I changed the query to DELETE FROM KEYS WHERE KEY_ID="7" it worked